# convert $scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress to string in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a rest call like `getParentSys.query({tl1Address: '172.28.71.155'}`
which works fine but I want to put the ip thats in the `$scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress` variable into the rest call as a variable.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress" id="adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress" ng-model="country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<html>IP Address of the Adtran<br>TL1 gateway.<br>Consult your Network Administrator<br>for this value." />
<label for="adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress">Adtran TL1 Gateway IP Address</label>
```

**Controller:**

```
function EightXXCtrl($scope, getParentSys) {
    $scope.getServingTA5000_8xx = function() {
        var matchingScope = "'" + $scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress + "'";
        getParentSys.query({
            tl1Address: '172.28.71.155'
        }, function() {
            $scope.log = "User saved";
        }, function() {
            $scope.log = "User could not be saved";
        });
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: so replace the string with the variable...not complicated

Comment: use getParentSys.query($scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress)

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked that's not correct assuming that the variable is an ip string value. However OP needs to show more details of what `scope.country` is

Comment: mmm i didn't account for that but whatever format his api is expecting its easy to send once you know it when you have access to that particular ip

Comment: $scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress is a value thats entered in a test box on a html page. The code for it is:

Comment: <input type="text" name="adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress" id="adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress" ng-model="country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress"
         data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<html>IP Address of the Adtran<br>TL1 gateway.<br>Consult your Network Administrator<br>for this value."
         />
         <label for="adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress">Adtran TL1 Gateway IP Address</label>
   </div>

Comment: check the answer below if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing how you are implementing your html and not having the full code for the service. I am assuming that you need to embed the `$scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress` as a string. Seeing your code, `getParentSys` must be your `service`.

**Simply in your Controller:**

**IF** `getParentSys.query({tl1Address: '172.28.71.155'});`

```
yourApp.controller('testController',function($scope,getParentSys){
       $scope.matchingScope = "'"+$scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress+"'";
       getParentSys.query({tl1Address: $scope.matchingScope});
})
```

**IF** `getParentSys.query({'tl1Address': '172.28.71.155'});`

```
yourApp.controller('testController',function($scope,getParentSys){
           $scope.matchingScope = "'"+$scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress+"'";
           getParentSys.query({'tl1Address': $scope.matchingScope});
    })
```

> There are other methods as well to achieve the above.

Comment: the var line in the following code seems to makes the app to fail

Comment: function EightXXCtrl($scope, getParentSys) { 
    
   $scope.getServingTA5000_8xx = function () {
     
     var matchingScope = "'"+$scope.country.adtranTL1GatewayIPAddress+"'"; 
     getParentSys.query({tl1Address: '172.28.71.155'},function(){ 
 $scope.log = "User saved";
     },function(){
 $scope.log = "User could not be saved";
     });
        
   }
    
}